# Last removed number in Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: number-theory

I want to find the last deleted number in Sieve of Eratosthenes when applied on numbers below 1000. How can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $n<1000$ is composite, it will be removed when its smallest prime factor is processed. $31<\sqrt{1000}<32$, so the smallest prime factor or $n$ can be at most $31$.